# Apple Mac mini SKU numbers difference

Tags: mac-mini

What is the meaning of the SKUs of Mac mini:

Difference between "MGEM2GU/A" and "MGEM2D/A"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MGEM2**/A is the marketing number of the base model: [Mac mini](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201894) (Late 2014) 1.4GHz dual-core Intel Core i5/4GB. MGEM2GU/A is the number for the Greek?/former Commonwealth of Independent States (except Russia) market and MGEM2D/A is for the German market.

Some more country/market identifiers: **LL** = US/Canada, **B** = UK, **BZ** = Brazil, **C** = Canada, **CH** = China, **E** = most spanish countries (Mexico, Spain, Argentina), **J** = Japan, **RU** = Russia, **X** = Australia/New Zealand etc.